# Error with VueJs router-link element

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, routerlink

Every time I click on one of my vuejs router-link elements in my app.blade.php page navigation bar, I end up getting an error on my console as seen below

```
 [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "to"

 found in

 ---> <RouterLink>
   <Root>
```

The code below shows how I implemented my router-links within my navigation bar.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @guest
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                        </li>
                    @else
                        <li class="nav-item"  id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="padding: 15px; ">

                               <router-link style="color:black;" :to="{ name: 'home' }">Menu<i class="fa fa-home" style="margin-left:8px;"></i></router-link>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item"  id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="padding: 15px;">

                               <router-link style="color:black;" :to="{ name: 'orders' }">Orders <i class="fa fa-coffee" style="margin-left:8px;"></i></router-link>
                        </li>



                        <li class="nav-item"  id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="padding: 15px;">

                               <router-link style="color:black;" :to="{ name: 'cart' }">Cart <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="margin-left:8px;"></i></router-link>
                        </li>
```

Can someone please explain why I get this error?

Comment: [Vue warn]: $attrs is readonly.

found in

---> <RouterLink>
       <Root>

Comment: That is the first error i get

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to change your `props` element inside vue component. Use `data` for that purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps someone.
My problem was that I registered a global mixin in `main.js` with the following function:

```
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    to(name, params) {
      this.$router.resolve({ name, params });
    },
  },
});
```

Just rename or remove this configuration and all **RouterLink** errors dissapear.